# Ubuntu: VLAN + bridge is not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking

'm trying to create a bridge (br0.5) that is linked to a VLAN (ID 5), for LXC (our containers needs a real IP address). The box won't connect to the default VLAN, and the port on the switch is configured as a trunk.

So I did this in /etc/network/interfaces. This is Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS.

```
auto enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet manual
up /sbin/ifconfig enp1s0f0 up || /bin/true
down /sbin/ifconfig enp1s0f0 down || /bin/true

auto enp1s0f0.5
iface enp1s0f0.5 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
bridge_ports enp1s0f0 
bridge_stp off 
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig enp1s0f0 up || /bin/true
up /sbin/ifconfig br0 up || /bin/true 

auto br0.5
iface br0.5 net static
address 192.168.5.77
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.5 
vlan-raw-device br0
```

Once I apply this configuration, a default route is added, the gateway is indeed 192.168.5.1. Problem is: I can't reach anything, can't even ping a host in the same VLAN. All interfaces are up.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in a bit wrong way.

You should include the actual VLAN interface to the bridge, so your configuration should look something like this:

```
auto enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet manual

auto enp1s0f0.5
iface enp1s0f0.5 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
bridge_ports enp1s0f0.5 
bridge_stp off 

auto br0
iface br0 net static
address 192.168.5.77
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.5
```

You don't need the separate `ifconfig` commands either, the networking subsystem takes care of those directly.

Comment: Merged the two br0 configuration together, and your solution worked just fine! Thanks.